# Way to change div order on vote

Tags: jquery

Looking for a method for reordering a div based on a vote using JQuery.

Comment: This isn't a programming problem, it's a shopping question. They don't do well here, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for the tip David. Lets rephrase the question to a method for reordering a div based on a vote using JQuery.

Comment: You should store your data in a data structure and re-render the divs when it changes. Then you can simply re-sort the data structure.

Comment: Then you'll need to, or 'should,' show some representative mark-up, and give an idea of the jQuery you're already using (if any). Also: *edit your question* to reflect the revised question before it's closed. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch out this http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists , hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Check this : http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/ it will help you sort your divs. The comparison function could use an array of votes returned from your ajax controller